# C++ recursion flow

Tags: c++, recursion

Could someone explain why is this printing hashtags per line from 1 to h. Because from my understanding the function is calling itself before even the for loop and it shouldn't print at all. If I move function calling below the for loop then it prints from h to 1 per line.

```
void draw (int h)
{
    if(h == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    draw(h - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "#";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Function calls happen in the order they are listed in the source. So first it recurses into a call with one less 'h' untill it hits zero. Then upon returning from that call it will continue with the std::cout loop. E.g print the first '#' then returns from that call and prints 2 '##' etc.

Comment: _"the function is calling itself before even the for loop"_ that is correct.  But what does it do **next**?

Comment: The big secret of recursive functions is that there is nothing special about recursive functions. It flows in exactly the same way as it would if you had called a different function.

Comment: @Drew Dormann very good question. Okay I got that part but I still can not understand why (if let's say h is 5) it prints single # on first iteration, then it prints ## on second and so on untill it prints 5 on the very last iteration. While from my understanding it should print from 5 hashtags on the first iteration to 1 on the last.

Comment: @Augis I think that will become very clear when you _step through your code in a debugger_.  Using a debugger is a vital component of C++ development.  Then you'll see `draw(1)` printing `#` before returning to `draw(2)` which then prints `##` and so on.

Comment: @Augis Alternatively you could add debug logging. For example `std::cout << "Entering draw with h = ' << h << '\n'` as first line and `std::cout << "Exiting draw with h = ' << h << '\n'` at the very end. I think then it will become clear.

Comment: @molbdnilo The big secret of recursive functions is what comes after the big secret of recursive functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the "substitution method" is often clarifying.

Let's look at a smaller example, `draw(2)`.

Replacing `h` with `2` in the function body gives

```
if(2 == 0)
{
    return;
}
draw(2 - 1);
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "#";
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

Since the first condition is false, we must do `draw(1)` before we can continue with the loop.
Substituting again gives

```
if(1 == 0)
{
    return;
}
draw(1 - 1);
for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "#";
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

The first condition is still false, so we need `draw(0)`:

```
if(0 == 0)
{
    return;
}
draw(0 - 1);
for(int i = 0; i < 0; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "#";
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

Now the first condition is true, so we return without doing anything, and can continue with the loop in `draw(1)`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "#";
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

which prints one character.
Then, we return to the loop in `draw(2)`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "#";
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

which prints two characters, and we're done.

You could also aid your reasoning by replacing the recursion with dedicated functions:

```
void draw_0() {}
void draw_1() { draw_0(); std::cout << "#\n";}
void draw_2() { draw_1(); std::cout << "##\n";}
void draw_3() { draw_2(); std::cout << "###\n";}
void draw_4() { draw_3(); std::cout << "####\n";}
void draw_5() { draw_4(); std::cout << "#####\n";}
```

and then consider what happens with `draw_5()`.

Answer (score 1):

When the function `draw` is called, its information (value of variables, code segment, etc) is pushed onto a stack. This stack grows more and more as you make your recursion calls. The stack for `draw(5)` for instance would be `draw(5)`, `draw(4)`, and so on with `draw(5)` being at the bottom of the recursion stack.

Now to avoid infinte recursion calls, your condition `(h == 0)` acts as a base case.

Once the base case is reached, the function `draw(0)` terminates and is popped off the top of the recursion stack. Now the prior procedures are then popped out of the stack in a LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) order and continue their execution which includes the for loop printouts.

For instance, the first printout would be a single #. This is due to the recursion call `draw(1)` being next on the stack after the base case `draw(0)` terminated. Remember that `draw(1)` still has the value of 1 for its parameter h, which leads to that single # printout. Once `draw(1)` is done with its execution `draw(2)` takes over which prints two # and so forth.

To visually see this recursion you could utilize more printouts in the `draw` function to give you an overview of the order of recursive calls, but I highly recommend getting familiar with using a debugger to step through your C++ code and clearly see the recursion.